# Admob Banner in LinearLayout with Libgdx Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, libgdx, admob

I am currently working on including admob ads into my first libgdx project.
I already managed to show a banner with a relative layout. but i would like to know what it would look like in a vertical LinearLayout, where the gameScreen is added first and then the banner is added. All code examples regarding linear layouts i have looked at so far where implemented in xml, but i would like to implement it via code.

this is what my current implementation with relative Layout looks like:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.addView(gameView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    setContentView(layout);
}
```

I tried to replace every "RelativeLayout" wih "LinearLayout" and layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL) but i guess thats not how LinearLayouts work. I only have little experience in Android app programming so i would appreciate any hints.

Edit: This is the (very basic) approach i tried myself (with and without the outcommented line, in both cases only the gameView is visible):

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        //layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.addView(gameView);
        layout.addView(bannerAdView);

        setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: Show us an example of how you used the LinearLayout.

Comment: okay, the lines have been added

Comment: @Doflaminhgo Hey. I found that you have deleted the question `"Room migration: Indices = null (“Migration didn't properly handle”)"`. Am facing the same issue and trying to figure it out. Can you help? Sorry for posting a comment here!

Comment: @vizsatiz well, the solution I tried is to create another table that follows exactly what room expects (you can find the necessary create-statement in a "schema"-file created by room). Then I copied all entries of the old table into the new one, deleted the old table and renamed the new one. This is kinda exhausting, but also the only solution I found :)

Comment: Oh thanks dude !! I tried that and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Create the layout
    Linearlayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    // Create the libgdx View
    View gameView = initializeForView(new YourGame(), false);

    // Create and setup the AdMob view
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxx");
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    // Add the libgdx view
    layout.addView(gameView);

    // Add the AdMob view
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);
```

This is a modified version from https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

Comment: this didn't work out either. i am currently solving it in the relatve layout with gameViewParams.bottomMargin = AdSize.BANNER.getHeightInPixels(this);. but by doing so the screen leaves a black stripe when there is no connection toload the banner

Comment: What exactly happened? Did the game screen draw over it again? If so, you can try using fragments.

Comment: I am not sure whether the gamescreen was drawn over the adView or the gamescreen just filled the whole screen and "pushed" the ad outside. Is the LinearLayout "match_parent" by default? if not, i might try setting this attribute